# ASP.NET: Using Request["param"] versus using Request.QueryString["param"] or Request.Form["param"]

Tags: asp.net, request, request.querystring, request.form

When accessing a form or query string value from code-behind in ASP.NET, what are the pros and cons of using, say:

```
// short way
string p = Request["param"];
```

instead of:

```
// long way
string p = Request.QueryString["param"]; // if it's in the query string or
string p = Request.Form["param"];        // for posted form values
```

I've thought about this many times, and come up with:

**Short way:**

- Shorter (more readable, easier for newbies to remember, etc)

**Long way:**

- No problems if there are a form value and query string value with same name (though that's not usually an issue)
- Someone reading the code later knows whether to look in URLs or form elements to find the source of the data (probably the most important point)

.

**So what other advantages/disadvantages are there to each approach?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **long way is better** because:

- It makes it easier (when reading the code later) to find **where the value is coming from** (improving readability)
- It's **marginally faster** (though this usually isn't significant, and only applies to first access)

In ASP.NET (as well as the equivalent concept in PHP), I always use what you are calling the "long form."  I do so out of the principle that I want to know exactly from where my input values are coming, so that I am ensuring that they get to my application the way I expect.  So, it's for input validation and security that I prefer the longer way.  Plus, as you suggest, I think the maintainability is worth a few extra keystrokes.

Answer (score 9):

the param collection includes all (4) collections:

1. Query-string parameters
2. Form fields
3. Cookies
4. Server variables

you can debate that searching in the combined collection is slower than looking into a specific one, but it is negligible to make a difference

Comment: +1 The only performance difference is that the first time `Params` is accessed, it needs to be constructed from the other collections. `NameValueCollection` uses a `Hashset` to store the values, so access is quick regardless of size.

Comment: I sometimes deliberately set up just `Request["param"]`. I do this so that I can use both POST and GET in other pages that point to this one but are for the same purpose (like a returnUrl to be used with OAuth for example). I certainly don't think that this should just be done by default due to laziness, though, for sure.